# How to convert a binary number into a decimal fraction in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i have been wondering if there is a way in which to convert binary numbers into decimal fractions.

I know how to change base as an example through this code

```
String binary = "11110010";

//I'd like to change this line so it produces a decimal value
String denary = int.parse(binary, radix: 2).toRadixString(10);
```

Comment: What decimal value would you expect?

Answer (score 7):

If anyone still wondering how to convert decimal to binary and the inverse:

```
  print(55.toRadixString(2)); // Outputs 110111
  print(int.parse("110111", radix: 2)); Outputs 55
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Converting binary to a fractional decimal

Answer (score 0):

```
int binaryToDecimal(int n)
 {
 int num = n;
 int dec_value = 0;

  // Initializing base value to 1, i.e 2^0
  int base = 1;

  int temp = num;
  while (temp) {
    int last_digit = temp % 10;
    temp = temp / 10;

    dec_value += last_digit * base;

    base = base * 2;
 }
return dec_value;
}

int main()
{
  int num = 10101001;
  cout << binaryToDecimal(num) << endl;
 }
```

This is my c++ solution but you can implement any language